# How to differientate the noise functions in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, noise, depolarizing-channel

In Qiskit, there are many different [Quantum Error Functions](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/aer_noise.html).
From my understanding, `pauli_error` represents the error rate of $X, Y, Z$ independently, and `deplolarizing_error` is a combination of these Pauli operators. Is it correct? Are the two channels belong to incoherent errors?

Moreover, can `phase_damping_error` and `amplitude_damping_error` be regarded as $Z$ and $X$ errors respectively? Are they coherent or incoherent errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to read the literature about these errors, they are not restricted to Qiskit. The textbook of Nielsen and Chuang has a very good chapter. In essence:

- Pauli error: if you assign this error to some gate (e.g. Hadamard), and you attach probabilities `(p_x, p_y, p_z)` to it, then after that gate is simulated, with probability `p_x`, an X gate will run, with probability `p_y`, a Y gate will run, and with probability `p_z`, a Z gate will run. Note that it's not the error rate of the X gate etc.
- Depolarizing: a special case of a Pauli error, where `p_x = p_y = p_z`.
- Amplitude damping and phase damping are not X and Z and are incoherent.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifying! To summarize my understanding, `Pauli_error` and `Depolarizing` are gate errors while `amplitude_damping` and `phase_damping` are thermal relaxation errors. Is that correct?

Comment: `amplitude_damping` and `phase_damping` are indeed thermal relaxation errors. I don't know what you mean by "gate errors", but `Pauli_error` and `Depolarizing` are unital.

Comment: Thanks! The gate errors that we obtain from the calibration data, such as pauli-X, square root of X, CNOT errors, do they correspond to any specific type of errors included in the error functions, or they are a combination of all the errors?

Comment: They don't correspond to a specific error. There's a mathematical proof that, for Clifford gates, the different errors are averaged to depolarizing, and this fact is somehow more-or-less used when calculating gate errors, using interleaved randomized benchmarking.